# ROSRUN ros cpp node creation for camera

Tags: ros

I am already having a one `catkin_ws` workspace which has some ros nodes and topic and all which make getting camera to it, means camera is engaged with those nodes and I have one cpp which runs with taking camera as input while running only like `./example -camera` which don't have any ros coding in it.

Now I want to covert that general `example.cpp` to ros cpp whicenter code here do `ros::init()` and get subscribe to that already running camera and give output video on realtime.

I am trying to understand whole thing but I don't know how to take camera video from already running node, means I want rosrun file which takes camera as it runs.

```
 cv::VideoCapture video;
 bool useCamera = true;

 if( useCamera )
  video.open(0);




#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

#include "../src/MSAC.h"

#include "../src/pedro.cpp"
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int uheight = 240;
int uwidth = 320;
int vthres = 60;
Size size(uwidth, uheight);
cv::Mat inputImg;
// std::vector<cv::Mat> vps;            // vector of vps: vps[vpNum], with vpNum=0...numDetectedVps

//it takes the label number which you want as output

Mat labelled_image(int label,int *arr_label[],Mat image)
{
  Mat temp(image.size(),CV_8UC1,Scalar(0));
  for(int i=0;i<image.rows;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<image.cols;j++)
    {
      if(label==arr_label[i][j])
      {
        temp.at<uchar>(i,j)=255;
      }
    }
  }

  return(temp);
}

void help()
{
  cout << "/*\n"
  << " **************************************************************************************************\n"
  << " * Vanishing point detection using Hough and MSAC \n"
  << " * ----------------------------------------------------\n"
  << " * \n"
  << " * Author:Marcos Nieto\n"
  << " * www.marcosnieto.net\n"
  << " * marcos.nieto.doncel@gmail.com\n"
  << " * \n"
  << " * Date:01/12/2011\n"
  << " **************************************************************************************************\n"
  << " * \n"
  << " * Usage: \n"
  << " *        -numVps     # Number of vanishing points to detect (at maximum) \n"
  << " *        -mode       # Estimation mode (default is NIETO): LS (Least Squares), NIETO\n"
  << " *        -video      # Specifies video file as input (if not specified, camera is used) \n"
  << " *        -image      # Specifies image file as input (if not specified, camera is used) \n"
  << " *        -verbose    # Actives verbose: ON, OFF (default)\n"
  << " *        -play       # ON: the video runs until the end; OFF: frame by frame (key press event)\n"
  << " *        -resizedWidth   # Specifies the desired width of the image (the height is computed to keep aspect ratio)\n"
  << " * Example:\n"
  << " *        vanishingPoint.exe -numVps 2 -video myVideo.avi -verbose ON\n"
  << " *        vanishingPoint.exe -numVps 2 -image myImage.jpg\n"
  << " *        vanishingPoint.exe -numVps 1 -play OFF -resizedWidth 640\n"
  << " * \n"
  << " * Keys:\n"
  << " *        Esc: Quit\n"
  << " */\n" << endl;
}

/** This function contains the actions performed for each image*/
void processImage(MSAC &msac, int numVps, cv::Mat &imgGRAY, cv::Mat &outputImg)
{
  cv::Mat imgCanny;

  // Canny
  cv::Canny(imgGRAY, imgCanny, 40, 65, 3);

  // Hough
  vector<vector<cv::Point> > lineSegments;
  vector<cv::Point> aux;
  #ifndef USE_PPHT
  vector<Vec2f> lines;
  cv::HoughLines( imgCanny, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 130);

  for(size_t i=0; i< lines.size(); i++)
  {
    float rho = lines[i][0];
    float theta = lines[i][1];

    double a = cos(theta), b = sin(theta);
    double x0 = a*rho, y0 = b*rho;

    Point pt1, pt2;
    pt1.x = cvRound(x0 + 1000*(-b));
    pt1.y = cvRound(y0 + 1000*(a));
    pt2.x = cvRound(x0 - 1000*(-b));
    pt2.y = cvRound(y0 - 1000*(a));

    aux.clear();
    aux.push_back(pt1);
    aux.push_back(pt2);
    lineSegments.push_back(aux);

    line(outputImg, pt1, pt2, CV_RGB(0, 0, 0), 1, 8);

  }
  #else
  vector<Vec4i> lines;
  int houghThreshold = 70;
  if(imgGRAY.cols*imgGRAY.rows < 400*400)
  houghThreshold = 100;

  cv::HoughLinesP(imgCanny, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, houghThreshold, 10,10);

  while(lines.size() > MAX_NUM_LINES)
  {
    lines.clear();
    houghThreshold += 10;
    cv::HoughLinesP(imgCanny, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, houghThreshold, 10, 10);
  }
  for(size_t i=0; i<lines.size(); i++)
  {
    Point pt1, pt2;
    pt1.x = lines[i][0];
    pt1.y = lines[i][1];
    pt2.x = lines[i][2];
    pt2.y = lines[i][3];
    line(outputImg, pt1, pt2, CV_RGB(0,0,0), 2);
    /*circle(outputImg, pt1, 2, CV_RGB(255,255,255), CV_FILLED);
    circle(outputImg, pt1, 3, CV_RGB(0,0,0),1);
    circle(outputImg, pt2, 2, CV_RGB(255,255,255), CV_FILLED);
    circle(outputImg, pt2, 3, CV_RGB(0,0,0),1);*/

    // Store into vector of pairs of Points for msac
    aux.clear();
    aux.push_back(pt1);
    aux.push_back(pt2);
    lineSegments.push_back(aux);
  }

  #endif

  // Multiple vanishing points
  std::vector<cv::Mat> vps;         // vector of vps: vps[vpNum], with vpNum=0...numDetectedVps
  std::vector<std::vector<int> > CS;    // index of Consensus Set for all vps: CS[vpNum] is a vector containing indexes of lineSegments belonging to Consensus Set of vp numVp
  std::vector<int> numInliers;

  std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > > lineSegmentsClusters;

  // Call msac function for multiple vanishing point estimation
  msac.multipleVPEstimation(lineSegments, lineSegmentsClusters, numInliers, vps, numVps);
  for(int v=0; v<vps.size(); v++)
  {
    printf("VP %d (%.3f, %.3f, %.3f)", v, vps[v].at<float>(0,0), vps[v].at<float>(1,0), vps[v].at<float>(2,0));
    fflush(stdout);
    double vpNorm = cv::norm(vps[v]);
    if(fabs(vpNorm - 1) < 0.001)
    {
      printf("(INFINITE)");
      fflush(stdout);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  // Draw line segments according to their cluster
  msac.drawCS(outputImg, lineSegmentsClusters, vps);

  // View
  namedWindow("Output", CV_WINDOW_KEEPRATIO);
  imshow("Output", outputImg);
  // imwrite("vanishingPoint.jpg", outputImg);

  // storing 'y' values of vanishing point and getting that 'y' value till which we will do processing on our image
  float one, two = 0.0;
  int x1, x2 = 1;
  vthres = 60;
  int tmax = uheight-120;
  if(vps.size() == 1)
  {
    x1 = vps[0].at<float>(0,0);
    if(x1 > 0 && x1 < uwidth){
      one = vps[0].at<float>(0,1);
      if(one <0) one = vthres;
      if(one > tmax) vthres = tmax;
      else vthres = one;
    }
  }
  else if(vps.size() == 2)
  {
    x1 = vps[0].at<float>(0,0);
    x2 = vps[1].at<float>(0,0);
    if(x1 > 0 && x1 < uwidth)
    {
      one = vps[0].at<float>(0,1);
      if(one <0) one = vthres;
    }
    else one = vthres;
    if(x2 > 0 && x2 < uwidth)
    {
      two = vps[1].at<float>(0,1);
      if(two<0) two = vthres;
    }
    else two = vthres;

    if(one > tmax && two > tmax) vthres = tmax;
    else if(one > tmax || two > tmax) vthres = (one > two) ? two : one;
    else vthres = (one > two) ? one : two;
  }
  else vthres = vthres;
  cout << "\nvanishing point: " << vthres << endl;


  // Resizing image considering vanishing point
  Mat img(inputImg, Rect(0,vthres,uwidth,uheight-vthres) );
  //    resize(img,img,size);
  cout << "\nUpdated Image size: (" << img.cols << " x " << img.rows << ')' <<  endl;

  /*Result of graph-segmentation*/
  cv::Mat output(img.size(),img.type());

  /*labelled image i.e each segment is assigned a particular label*/
  cv::Mat label_image(img.size(),img.type(),Scalar(0));

  /*Parameters for graph-segmentation*/
  int k = 800;
  int min_size = 50;

  pedro p = pedro(img, k, min_size);

  // cv::imshow("input image",img);

  p.Evaluate();

  cout<<"number of segments = "<<p.num_ccs<<endl;

  p.output_seg.copyTo(output);

  namedWindow(" segmented output ",CV_WINDOW_KEEPRATIO);
  cv::imshow(" segmented output ",output);
  // imwrite("segmented.jpg", output);

  /**Suppose you want to check a segment number then uncomment the code below and provide
  * the label number**/

  // Storing labels in a Mat object labels
  Mat labels(img.size(),CV_8UC1,Scalar(0));
  for(int i=0;i<img.rows;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<img.cols;j++){
      labels.at<uchar>(i,j) = p.labels_seg[i][j];
    }
  }

  // detecting road label
  float total = 0.0;
  Mat label1(labels, Rect(100, uheight-vthres-15, 150, 15));
  Mat label2(labels, Rect(110, uheight-vthres-20, 120, 20));
  Mat label3(labels, Rect(120, uheight-vthres-30, 80, 30));

  total = ((sum(label1)[0] / 2250) + (sum(label2)[0] / 2400) + (sum(label3)[0] / 2400)) / 3;
  // total = ceil(total);

  int label_no = total;
  cout << "\nlabel: " << label_no << "\ttotal: " << total << endl;
  label_image = labelled_image(label_no, p.labels_seg, img); //Suppose you want label 1

  cv::namedWindow("labelimage", CV_WINDOW_KEEPRATIO);
  cv::imshow("labelimage",label_image);
  // imwrite("boundary.jpg", label_image);

  // Find contours
  vector<vector<Point> > contours;
  vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
  RNG rng(12345);
  findContours( label_image, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );

  // Draw contours
  Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( label_image.size(), CV_8UC3 );
  for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
  {
    Scalar color = Scalar( rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255) );
    drawContours( drawing, contours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point() );
  }

  // display contours
  namedWindow("Contours", CV_WINDOW_KEEPRATIO);
  imshow("Contours", drawing);
  // imwrite("drawing.jpg", drawing);

  // vector for boundary points
  vector<int>bdp;

  // finding boundary points
  for(int i= 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
  {
    for(int j= 0; j < contours[i].size();j++) // run until j < contours[i].size();
    {
      if(contours[i][j].y == uheight-vthres-2){
        bdp.push_back(contours[i][j].x);
      }
    }
  }

  // sdist is safe-distance
  int right,left=0;
  int sdist = 10;
  for(int i=0; i < bdp.size(); i++)
  {
    cout << "\nCorner Point: (" << bdp[i] << ", " << uheight-vthres-2 << ")" << endl;
    if(bdp[i]-(uwidth/2) > 0) right = bdp[i]- (uwidth/2) -sdist;
    else left = -1 * ((uwidth/2) - bdp[i] - sdist);
  }

  // displaying boundary distances
  cout << "\nLeft Distance: " << left << "\tRight Distance: " << right << endl;

}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  // time starts now
  clock_t tStart = clock();

  // Images
  Mat imgGRAY;
  Mat outputImg;

  // Other variables
  char *videoFileName = 0;
  char *imageFileName = 0;
  cv::VideoCapture video;
  bool useCamera = true;
  int mode = MODE_NIETO;
  int numVps = 1;
  bool playMode = true;
  bool stillImage = false;
  bool verbose = false;

  int procWidth = -1;
  int procHeight = -1;
  cv::Size procSize;

  // Start showing help
  // help();

  // Parse arguments
  if(argc < 2)
  return -1;
  for(int i=1; i<argc; i++)
  {
    const char* s = argv[i];

    if(strcmp(s, "-video" ) == 0)
    {
      // Input video is a video file
      videoFileName = argv[++i];
      useCamera = false;
    }
    else if(strcmp(s,"-image") == 0)
    {
      // Input is a image file
      imageFileName = argv[++i];
      stillImage = true;
      useCamera = false;
    }
    else if(strcmp(s, "-resizedWidth") == 0)
    {
      procWidth = atoi(argv[++i]);
    }
    else if(strcmp(s, "-verbose" ) == 0)
    {
      const char* ss = argv[++i];
      if(strcmp(ss, "ON") == 0 || strcmp(ss, "on") == 0
      || strcmp(ss, "TRUE") == 0 || strcmp(ss, "true") == 0
      || strcmp(ss, "YES") == 0 || strcmp(ss, "yes") == 0 )
      verbose = true;
    }
    else if(strcmp(s, "-play" ) == 0)
    {
      const char* ss = argv[++i];
      if(strcmp(ss, "OFF") == 0 || strcmp(ss, "off") == 0
      || strcmp(ss, "FALSE") == 0 || strcmp(ss, "false") == 0
      || strcmp(ss, "NO") == 0 || strcmp(ss, "no") == 0
      || strcmp(ss, "STEP") == 0 || strcmp(ss, "step") == 0)
      playMode = false;
    }
    else if(strcmp(s, "-mode" ) == 0)
    {
      const char* ss = argv[++i];
      if(strcmp(ss, "LS") == 0)
      mode = MODE_LS;
      else if(strcmp(ss, "NIETO") == 0)
      mode = MODE_NIETO;
      else
      {
        perror("ERROR: Only LS or NIETO modes are supported\n");
      }
    }
    else if(strcmp(s,"-numVps") == 0)
    {
      numVps = atoi(argv[++i]);
    }
  }

  // Open video input
  if( useCamera )
  video.open(0);
  else
  {
    if(!stillImage)
    // video.open(videoFileName);
    video = VideoCapture(videoFileName);
  }

  // Check video input
  int width = 0, height = 0, fps = 0, fourcc = 0;

  if(!stillImage)
  {
    if( !video.isOpened() )
    {
      printf("ERROR: can not open camera or video file\n");
      return -1;
    }
    else
    {
      // Show video information
      width = (int) video.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
      height = (int) video.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
      fps = (int) video.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
      fourcc = (int) video.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC);

      if(!useCamera)
      printf("Input video: (%d x %d) at %d fps, fourcc = %d\n", width, height, fps, fourcc);
      else
      printf("Input camera: (%d x %d) at %d fps\n", width, height, fps);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    inputImg = cv::imread(imageFileName);
    if(inputImg.empty())
    return -1;

    resize(inputImg,inputImg,size);
    // size of image
    width = inputImg.cols;
    height = inputImg.rows;

    printf("Input image: (%d x %d)\n", width, height);

    playMode = false;
  }

  // Resize
  if(procWidth != -1)
  {

    procHeight = height*((double)procWidth/width);
    procSize = cv::Size(procWidth, procHeight);

    printf("Resize to: (%d x %d)\n", procWidth, procHeight);
  }
  else
  procSize = cv::Size(width, height);

  // Create and init MSAC
  MSAC msac;
  msac.init(mode, procSize, verbose);


  int frameNum=0;
  for( ;; )
  {
    if(!stillImage)
    {
      printf("\n-------------------------\nFRAME #%6d\n", frameNum);
      frameNum++;

      // Get current image
      video >> inputImg;
    }

    if( inputImg.empty() )
    break;

    resize(inputImg,inputImg,size);

    // Resize to processing size
    //      cv::resize(inputImg, inputImg, procSize);

    // Color Conversion
    if(inputImg.channels() == 3)
    {
      cv::cvtColor(inputImg, imgGRAY, CV_BGR2GRAY);
      inputImg.copyTo(outputImg);
    }
    else
    {
      inputImg.copyTo(imgGRAY);
      cv::cvtColor(inputImg, outputImg, CV_GRAY2BGR);
    }
    // ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    // Process
    // ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    processImage(msac, numVps, imgGRAY, outputImg);

    printf("Time taken: %.2fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    if(playMode)
    cv::waitKey(1);
    else
    cv::waitKey(0);

    char q = (char)waitKey(1);

    if( q == 27 )
    {
      printf("\nStopped by user request\n");
      break;
    }

    if(stillImage)
    break;
  }

  if(!stillImage)
  video.release();

  return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that you have to do in your main is:

```
ros::init(argc, argv, "Nome_of_the_node"); //This is to initialize ros
ros::NodeHandle nh;
```

This is a nodehandle for this node and can be used to publish, subscribe to topics and to get parameters from file. In the last lines of your main you have to write:

```
ros::spin();
```

This will keep your node active and it will update everycallback at the arrival of a new message.
Next step, you want to get the video from the running camera. In order to do that, you have to subscribe to the topic that the camera is publishing. You can find this topic by writing on your terminal `rostopic list`. When you find the right topic you have to write `rostopic info topic_name`. This will give you the type of message that your camera is publishing on that node. Suppose that it is `sensor_msgs/Image`. After that, in your cpp, you have to subscribe your node to that topic:

```
ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe<sensor_msgs::Image>("topic_name", num_message_in_queue, callbackname);
```

Then you have to create this callback:

```
void callbackname(const sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr& msg)
```

where msg will have an image of your video.

For further references I suggest you to do this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials